# How to hide/show back/next button with JavaScript in a Rails from wizard?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, wizard

I've created a wizard form with this gem: https://github.com/stephenbaldwin/fuelux-rails

Everything is working in terms of getting to the next and previous steps. However, what's a 'rails way' to hide the 'prev' button on first step and show only the 'submit' button on last step? Is this something I'd do do in js?

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@wizard) do |f| %>

  <div>
    <div id="MyWizard" class="wizard">
      <ul class="steps">
        <li data-target="#step1" class="active"><span class="badge badge-info">1</span>Step 1<span class="chevron"></span></li>
        <li data-target="#step2"><span class="badge">2</span>Step 2<span class="chevron"></span></li>
        <li data-target="#step3"><span class="badge">3</span>Step 3<span class="chevron"></span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="step-content">
      <div class="step-pane active" id="step1">
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :field1 %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :field1 %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="step-pane" id="step2">
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :field2 %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :field2 %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="step-pane" id="step3">
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :field3 %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :field3 %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-mini" id="btnWizardPrev" value="prev">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-mini" id="btnWizardNext" value="next"></br>

      <div>
        <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-primary' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

application.js file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#MyWizard').on('change', function(e, data) {
        console.log('change');
        if(data.step===3 && data.direction==='next') {
            // return e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $('#MyWizard').on('changed', function(e, data) {
        console.log('changed');
    });
    $('#MyWizard').on('finished', function(e, data) {
        console.log('finished');
    });
    $('#btnWizardPrev').on('click', function() {
        $('#MyWizard').wizard('previous');
    });
    $('#btnWizardNext').on('click', function() {
        $('#MyWizard').wizard('next','foo');
    });
    $('#btnWizardStep').on('click', function() {
        var item = $('#MyWizard').wizard('selectedItem');
        console.log(item.step);
    });
});
```

Side note/question - is there a way to put this .js in my asset pipeline without storing it in application.js? I tried to create a separate .js under javascripts but it dosen't pull in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript file replace this block

```
$('#MyWizard').on('change', function(e, data) {
    console.log('change');
    if(data.step===3 && data.direction==='next') {
        // return e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

with following block: **(UPDATED)**

```
$('#MyWizard').on('change', function(e, data) {
  console.log('change');
  $('#wizard-submit').hide(); //hide the submit button on each step.
  if(data.step === 3 && data.direction === 'next') {
    // return e.preventDefault();
    $('#wizard-submit').show(); //show the submit button only on last(3rd in your case) step.
  }

  switch(data.step) {
    case 1:
      if(data.direction === 'next')
        $('#btnWizardPrev').show();
      else
        $('#btnWizardPrev').hide();

      $('#btnWizardNext').show();
      break;
    case 2:
      if(data.direction === 'next') {
        $('#btnWizardPrev').show();
        $('#btnWizardNext').hide();
      }
      else {
        $('#btnWizardPrev').hide();
        $('#btnWizardNext').show();
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      // I would recommend to show the prev button on last step but hide the next button.
      if(data.direction === 'next')
        $('#btnWizardNext').hide();
      else
        $('#btnWizardNext').show();

      $('#btnWizardPrev').show();
      break;
    default:
      $('#btnWizardPrev').show();
      $('#btnWizardNext').show();
  }
});
```

The above code will show/hide the buttons based on the step you're in.

And for you second question: are you specifying the `//= require_tree .` in the **application.js**. If yes then try enclosing the code in `$(document).ready(function(){..code goes here..})`

**UPDATE** See the updated code above. I am not sure if this is the correct way, but I am able to get it working this way.

Also add `#btnWizardPrev { display: none; }`
**Assumption**: There are three steps in the form. If there are more you would need to add more cases in switch statement. Basically you'll need to break the **case 2:** statement in that case. In `case 2:` the `next` condition is for removing the next button, so in case there are more steps, move the `next` condition to second last step.

**UPDATE** Replace your submit button code with `<%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-primary', :id => 'wizard-submit' %>`. This will simply add **id** attribute to your submit button. You can use any value to be its id. Then just hide the submit button by adding this css `#wizard-submit { dispay: none }` and then use the above updated jquery code in your javascript file.

Comment: Hum. So the first step shows both next and prev buttons. Then when I go to step two, only next shows when I'd like to see prev. It seems that the triggers should be associated with the steps instead of the cases. Also, I'd like the f.submit button to show up only on last step. Let me think on that and get back to this question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: try printing the result of `data.step` in above block. and update the result for all the steps.

Comment: I meant add `alert(data.step)` or `console.log(data.step)` after `$('#MyWizard').on('change', function(e, data) {` line and see what they return and by updating I meant tell us what happen when you do so. :) Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Does Case represent the steps, or should I do a switch(data.step) { block } for each step? After adding adding an alert, it seems to be changing the buttons based on # of clicks.

Comment: Awesome. This mostly works - I still see the back button at first load on step 1, but its gone from step 1 if I go to step 2 and then back again. I'll try to find a way to hide it on first load.

Comment: I had mentioned that.. **Also add #btnWizardPrev { display: none; }** in your stylesheet. It will hide the previous button initially. :)

Comment: That's right. Works great now. Thanks for all the help! Looks like I need to study JavaScript more in depth. Cheers.

Comment: I can't say that.. As it took me to answer it more than a day. :( as I had to create a sample app for the same to see what exactly was happening.

Comment: One thing I still can't figure out is how to hide the submit button on all but the last step. I've now put <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn btn-primary' %> within the same div grouping as the prev/next buttons. Would I use $("submit").hide() in my coffee? This seems to make sense, but it dosen't work.

Comment: I have updated the code. Check it and let me know if doesn't solve your problem. :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks once again. Submit button is showing up in first step. I think with a little work, this could be packed up into its own gem as an alternative to the Wicked gem. I've put the demo app up on github: https://github.com/cpursley/wizardfuel - I made a few changes to the form, changed the init javascript over to coffee and changed less to plain css since I’m using sass. Let me know if you'd be interested in collaborating and turning this into an open-source gem : )

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I will look into the repo and would love to contribute. :) But I am busy for few days, I will have a look at it after I am done with my current work. And I had added the css to hide the submit button in first step. `#wizard-submit { dispay: none }` This should do the extra work. ;)

Comment: Hey, no need to apologize - you don't owe me anything ; ) We can work on it whenever you want. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, figured out a solution - add   $("#wizard-submit").hide()
  $("#btnWizardPrev").attr("disabled", true) before the "change" attribute (coffeescript).

Answer (score 0):

The wizard plugin already disables the previous button on the first step. It looks for a `button.btn-prev` located in the wizard container

```
<div id="myWizard" class="wizard">
  <div class="actions">
    <button class="btn btn-mini btn-prev"> <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>Prev</button>
    <button class="btn btn-mini btn-next" data-last="Finish">Next<i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
  </div>
```

If you'd like to hide the disabled previous button you could target it with css to avoid javascript

```
.wizard button.btn-prev[disabled] {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I've tried the above 'actions div' in my view. But every time I click a next or prev button, it submits the entire form. Maybe I have something wrong in my application.js?